# re-updating the page state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

There are 2 pages: the first loads an array of posts with a jsonplaceholder, the second displays the body of a specific post by clicking on the post.

When I return from the post page to the page with all the posts, the data is updated and re-requested.

How can I save the page state?

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  const getPostsData = async () => {
    try {
      const postsData = await getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      setData(postsData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { getPostsData() }, [])

  useEffect(() => { setPosts(data) }, [data])

  posts.map(post => <Link to={`${post.id}`} key={post.id}><li className="list-group-item" >{post.title}</li></Link>)
```

I use 2 states. One is for loading data, and the second is for displaying. I need it for sorting and searching.

Comment: Please create a sandbox for this code.

Comment: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-butterfly-s2o5mo)

Comment: you should create a global store for it, using redux or useContext hook for this purpose .

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case it's better to use redux , context or react-query, but if you don't want to, you must avoid using Link for the child component because when you change route your previous state will be removed
you can simply show post detail as a modal or part of the main page